# uploading ec2 instance to aws using windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I need to upload a centOS bundle from windows cmd to AWS. How can I do that?

In ec2-api-tools ec2-upload-bundle.cmd is not present.

How can i use that command in windows cmd? Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tools from http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351

this includes the windows cmd files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your point is probably that AWS says to use [ec2-upload-bundle.cmd](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-loopback-s3-linux.html), but that file does  not exist in the **API tools**.

Your problem is that the **AMI tools** are separate.  Get them from [Amazon EC2 AMI Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/368).  The tools are written in Ruby.  After installing Ruby, you might have to play with the commands to get them to work on Windows.

Comment: I got it If we want to upload linux OS, we have to use linux box only.